# How to scale in paper js

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, paperjs

I am trying to write a condition inside the view.onFrame (paper js) which is update function in normal canvas.

//Declaring

```
let number = 74;
let minus = true;




 view.onFrame = function(event) {
```

//Start conditioning
// if number become 75 and minus is true Number will start decreasing

```
if(number <= 75 && minus == true){
         number -= 1;
         minus = true;
      }
```

//if number reach 0 number will increase up to 75 and the condition become false

```
 else if(number == 0){
     number += 1;
     minus = false;
  }
```

//else the minus become true again

```
else {
minus = true;
}
```

The problem is that the condition never become true

Comment: `==` is used for comparison, if you're trying to reassign a value to `minus`, use `=`

Comment: @Titus Sorry my mistake  when I copying into stack over flow.
I already changed it back. Inside the code its is written in = . But not working

Comment: I see, in that case, the `else if` statement will never be reached because `0` is less then `75` and `minus` is never changed to `false` beside inside this condition.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with the structuring of your logic. You want to start at 75 and decrement to 0, then back up to 75, but let's look at your logic.

```
if(number <= 75 && minus == true){
  number -= 1;
  minus = true;
} 
else if (number == 0) {
  number += 1;
  minus = false;
}
```

The first condition, `number <= 75` is true even when `number == 0` (0 is less than or equal to 75 after all), so it will always begin to execute the first `if` statement and never get to the `else if` statement. On top of that, you are only executing `number += 1` when `number` is EXACTLY (`==`) 0. So even if you did clear up your logic, the output of that code would look like 75, 74, 73... 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 ...

What you want instead is to check whether you exit the bounds that you've set, and if you have, change whether you're incrementing or decrementing:

```
if (number > 75) { minus = true }
if (number < 1)  { minus = false }

if (minus) { number -= 1 } else { number += 1 }
```